# Get a reference to the AWSS3 object

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a photo from my iOS app to Amazon S3 successfully. I need to get the publicly accessible URL for that photo. Instead of building the URL manually, I use the following way to do that.

```
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { task in
    if let error = task.error {
        print("Upload failed: \(error.code) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if let exception = task.exception {
        print("Upload failed: \(exception)")
    }

    if task.result != nil {
        print("Successfully uploaded!")

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoRegionType, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        let aws3 = AWSS3(configuration: configuration)
        let publicURL = aws3.configuration.endpoint.URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).URLByAppendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
        print(publicURL)
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works well and I get proper the public URL.

```
https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/DAEF70E9-495A-40B4-B853-3B337486185D-4988-00000E22AB8E25A6.jpg
```

I have two problems.

1). Initializing it this way `AWSS3(configuration: configuration)` is deprecated now.

2). This while initializing code already happens inside the App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoRegionType, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

However trying to call the `endpoint` property from this configuration returns nil.

So what I'm looking to do is this. I don't want to repeat the initializing code in both App Delegate and here. So if there's a way to get a reference to the already initialized object in App Delegate, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get an instance of S3 object with `AWSS3.defaultS3()`. So I could construct the public URL like this.

```
let publicURL = AWSS3.defaultS3().configuration.endpoint.URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).URLByAppendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the following API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/registerS3WithConfiguration:forKey:

The SDK would hold the object for you and can always fetch it by using S3ForKey: mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/S3ForKey:

There are code snippets in the API reference demonstrating the usage.

-Rohan